# Understanding a detail about functions

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

Let $\sigma, \tau, \pi$ be functions such that the following compositions make sense.

Assume the following is true: $\sigma$ is surjective(not sure this is needed here), and for $\sigma$ and $\tau$ exists a unique isomorphism $\theta^{-1}$ such that $\sigma = \theta^{-1}\tau$.

How do we deduce that:

1)For $\sigma, \tau$ exists a unique isomorphism $\theta$ such that $\theta\sigma = \tau$

2)Deduce from 1): For $\sigma, \tau, \pi$ exists a unique isomorphism $\theta$ such that $\theta\sigma\pi = \tau\pi$.

It seems true, but I feel a little lost there, don't think I can provide a rigorous proof.

Answer (score 1):

(a) Isomorphisms are bijective, so are invertible.

(b) This is the definition of equality of (compositions of) functions.  I.e., the two sides agree on every possible input.

Comment: Oh, I know about bijections being invertible. And I know that if $f = g$, then $fh = gh$. It's uniqueness that bothers me. How to prove it persists through compositions. Am I overthinking it? Not sure.

Comment: I think you are not giving the uniqueness of $\theta$ sufficient explanation.

Comment: Inverse functions in general must be unique, this is a consequence of the fact that the original function is an isomorphism (i.e. it's one-to-one, onto).

Comment: What about 2)? I think we can deduce it from 1) only if $\pi$ is an epimorphism, that is, surjective? Is that so?

Comment: Sure if you are given surjective function $\theta$ and it has an inverse, that inverse is unique as an inverse for $\theta$.  But that is not how I understand the claim in (1) that the isomorphism $\theta$ is unique.

Comment: @Jxt921 : $\pi$ is some map taking each input to some output.  Then, whether you follow $\pi$ by $\tau$ or by $\sigma \theta$ they do the same thing to that output.

Comment: @hardmath : A function is a collection of input-output pairs.  A bijection is a collection of pairs where each input is unique and the union of inputs is the domain and each output is unique and the union of the outputs is the codomain.  Lack of uniqueness would imply a function that was all the same pairs as $\theta$ but that when you reversed the pairs you did not recover $\theta^{-1}$.  Which pair magically transmogrified into something else when it was reversed?